# Find the largest contiguous sum of two or more integers in an array of positive or negative integers?

Tags: c#, interview-questions

I received an interview question: Find the largest contiguous sum of two or more integers in an array of positive or negative integers.

I wrote a brute force solution, which is slow at O(n^2). Is there a faster solution? Sorry in advance if this question was already asked. I couldn't find an answer that accounts for the sum being at least 2 integers, and having negative numbers.

```
static int maxSum(int[] nums, int minArrayLen = 1) {
  int maxSum = Int32.MinValue;
  int curSum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++) {
    curSum = nums[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Length; j++) {
      curSum += nums[j];
      maxSum = Math.Max(curSum, maxSum);
    }
  }
  return maxSum;
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to use the variable `minArrayLen ` in the function, that could be bad in an interview.

Comment: @pacmaninbw you are right. My original code had a bunch more comments and an exception checker at the beginning. I removed those to make the code more readable for this post, but I forgot to remove the optional param.

Comment: @drspaceman0 Actually, posting code in a question on Code Review is a little different than doing so on Stack Overflow. Here, you should _not_ try to remove parts of the code because that prevents answerers from providing accurate reviews. You might even get feedback on your code comments, so you should probably not remove those as well.

Comment: As @41686d6564 mentioned you should post the entire function. There are some very experienced code readers here.

Comment: p.s. "contiguous sum" could be interpreted a number of ways. Do you have the original wording of the problem to post? If not, can you go into more detail on the problem definition?